# Google Sheets QUERY...WHERE stopped working

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-query-language

I use the Google Sheets SQL-ish [Query](https://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1388882) function to summarize data in a number of my spreadsheets. This has been working well for years, albeit slowly.

Today, I'm having problems with some of my queries - specifically with some that compare dates in the source data to `TODAY()`.

To demonstrate, here's a [link to a shared spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AmkSPNhhUowadF9sVGUxWXQtbU13cnc0RjJZQnpaWVE&usp=sharing) that I've used to reproduce the problem on fake data.

**Edit:** Example has been updated with AdamL's suggestion.

[image]

The source data is in range `A1:D6`, with columns "Serial No.", "Type", "Location", and "Warranty Expiration". The last column is a date.

This function in `A9` summarizes all data:

```
=query(A1:D6,"select B, count(A) group by B pivot C")
```

...like so:

[image: =query(A1:D6,"select B, count(A) group by B pivot C")]

Here's the thing. If I try to filter using `WHERE` and `DATE()`, the Query seems to break down completely. What I want is a table that looks like the one above, but including only data rows that have a date in column `D` that is in the past.

```
=query(A1:D6,"select B, count(A) where D < now() group by B pivot C")
```

[image: =query(A1:D6,"select B, count(A) where D < now() group by B pivot C")]

If I change the filter to something not involving dates, I get the expected output:

[image: =query(A1:D6,"select B, count(A) where B='Mech' group by B pivot C")]

How do I get this to give me the summary I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The now() [scalar function](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#scalar_functions) returns a datetime value, and you have date values in the source data. Comparisons between the two will unfortunately fail. The workaround is to convert now() to a date value:

`=QUERY(A1:D6;"select B, count(A) where D < toDate(now()) group by B pivot C")`

---

As an aside, there is a limitation (bug?) with the QUERY function whereby the now() scalar function does not (necessarily) operate in the time zone of your spreadsheet, and there doesn't appear to be any way of modifying this behaviour. I believe that the now() scalar function will always return the current time in Pacific Daylight Time (eg US west coast). So for me, right now in Brisbane, Australia, toDate(now()) used in a QUERY select clause returns yesterday's date.

The safer bet is to use a spreadsheet function to generate today's date, and concatenate that into the QUERY clause:

`=QUERY(A1:D6;"select B, count(A) where D < date '"&TEXT(GoogleClock();"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' group by B pivot C")`

Comment: I'll give that a shot. In my real sheets, I have datetime values, and my queries just stopped working sometime in the past few days!

Comment: Ah I see. Well datetime values *should* work, notwithstanding that time zone issue. I just tested a few that seemed to be retrieved OK.

Comment: Gold star! That did the trick. It seems that they've tightened up comparison of `date` vs `datetime`.